# SpriteKit -- SKTexture PreloadTextures EXC_BAD_ACCESS Crash

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, textures, exc-bad-access

I am trying to preload textures. When I preload a full `SKTextureAtlas`, my code works fine. But when I try to preload `SKTextures`, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Here is my code:

```
[SKTexture preloadTextures:@[@"steady_beat-animation-shark_4"] withCompletionHandler:blah, blah];
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error no matter what texture I input, how many I input, or where I call this code (in an `SKScene` or an `SKSpriteNode`).

The error is:

```
objc_msgSend
Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1f)
```

Here are the call stack symbols if that's helpful:

```
(lldb) po [NSThread callStackSymbols]
<_NSCallStackArray 0x16f738f0>(
0   ???                                 0x038a8b74 0x0 + 59411316,
1   Edify-Testing-Debug                 0x000c9d89 main + 0,
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0068cad3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10,
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x006967c5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 968,
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00697885 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108,
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x32301e25 _pthread_wqthread + 668,
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x32301b78 start_wqthread + 8
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKTexture preloadTextures:` takes an `NSArray` of `SKTextures`, not `NSString`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/preloadTextures:withCompletionHandler:

```
[SKTexture preloadTextures:@[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"steady_beat-animation-shark_4"]] withCompletionHandler:blah, blah];
```

Comment: Yeah, you'd think this would be a compile time message or something.